# Rsync pull from /home/*/ to same dir

Tags: rsync

Running the following command:

`/usr/bin/rsync -avuz --rsh=ssh --temp-dir=/tmp --port=55556 --rsync-path=/usr/bin/rsync REMOTEIP:/home/*/mail/ /home/*/mail > /var/log/rsync/test.log 2>&1`

Results in `rsync: mkdir "/home/*/mail" failed: No such file or directory (2)`

Is there anyway to use the expanded path on the local side to get username instead of the literal `*`?

I want to only pull mail directory from all home dirs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one target directory. In your case, the common target is `/home` or `/`.  So to get the remote path duplicated in the local target use the `-R` (long version `--relative`) option:

```
... --relative REMOTEIP:/home/*/mail/ /
```

You may like to add `--no-implied-dirs` to this to avoid rsync trying to copy attributes for the given directories (but not any subdirectories).
Check first with `-n` to ensure this will do what you expect.

Comment: Thanks that was close but resulted in the loss of `/home/user/` prefix, everything went into `/mail/`

I've added my answer but cannot accept for 2 days

Comment: I use `-R` this way all the time, and it always copies the complete path, so `home/user/mail/` is placed under the target directory, whatever it is. Another useful thing with `-R` is that it doesn't matter if you have a trailing slash in the source directories.

Comment: Oh my mistake, completely missed the capital R.

Comment: My fault too; I should have used the more explicit long arg, `--relative`. Edited the post for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

The following also accomplishes it but meuh's way is cleaner.

`/usr/bin/rsync -avuz --rsh=ssh --temp-dir=/tmp --port=55556 --include='*/mail' --include='*/mail/**' --exclude='*/*' --rsync-path=/usr/bin/rsync REMOTEIP:/home/ /home > /var/log/rsync/test.log 2>&1`